# How do I get JAXB to choose enum?

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb

I'm trying to convert the XML text to a Java object, but there is a number in the `prQueryStatus` XML attribute. The type of the Java field is an `enum`. Is there a way for JAXB to choose my `enum`?

Strxml:

```
 <custom prQueryStatus="1" ></custom>
```

faulty row:

```
  CustAttrPrQuery custom = (CustAttrPrQuery)XmlOperations.deserializeFromXML(CustAttrPrQuery.class, strXmlCustom);
```

XmlOperations.deserializeFromXML():

```
public static Object deserializeFromXML(Class obj, String strXml) {

    Object result = null;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    try {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(strXml);

        result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        return result;

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
       return new String("-3 JAXB deSerialize Error");
    }

}
```

CustAttrPrQuery:

```
@XmlAccessorType(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = CustAttrPrQuery.RootElement)
public class CustAttrPrQuery {

    public final static String RootElement = "custom";

    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute
    private PrQueryStatus prQueryStatus = PrQueryStatus.NONE;

    public PrQueryStatus getPrQueryStatus() {
        return prQueryStatus;
    }

    public void setPrQueryStatus(PrQueryStatus prQueryStatus) {
        this.prQueryStatus = prQueryStatus;
    }

}
```

enum:

```
public enum PrQueryStatus {
  NONE,
  ACIK,
  TUMU
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate your enum type with [`@XmlEnum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnum.html)
and its constants with [`@XmlEnumValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html),
so that JAXB will know how to map from XML attributes (`"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`) to the enum constants (`NONE`, `ACIK`, `TUMU`):

```
@XmlEnum
public enum PrQueryStatus {
    @XmlEnumValue("0") NONE,
    @XmlEnumValue("1") ACIK,
    @XmlEnumValue("2") TUMU
}
```